# Connect VPN from the command line

Tags: network, command-line, vpn

I am attempting to get some GitHub macOS runners to perform some actions on each push to a particular Github repo.

This requires a VPN connection to an AWS EFS volume.

I can get it running on my Mac where I am there to click the right things in dialogs. On GitHub every client I've tried puts up an unseen dialog then times out the connection attempt to fail.

I've tried `Tunnelblick` (using `tunnelblickctrl`) and the `OpenVPN Connect` client but both fail. Since the VPN uses certificates to authenticate I don't know of a way using `networksetup`.

Anyone know of a better command line VPN client?